# What does this code on my site's footer do?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code on my site's footer

```
<div id="ajax_data" style="display:none"></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="__cronlog">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#__cronlog').html(unescape('%3Cimg%20src%3D%22' + GET_BASE_URL + '/cronlog/run/<?php echo time(); ?>%22%20width%3D%221%22%20height%3D%221%22%20/%3E'));
        });

    </script>
</div>
```

What does this code do? Is it a virus? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try `alert(unescape('blah blah blah'))` and see what it's inserting into your page?

Comment: flagged as too broad: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions

Answer (score 1):

You have code on your web page you don't understand? Why?

It is a simple [web bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug) to execute a request to a URL, this one just logs the access time.

URL decoded:

<img src="GET_BASE_URL/cronlog/run/<?php echo time(); ?>" width="1" height="1" />

Where GET_BASE_URL is the base URL of the page. So it accesses your site, probably providing statistics--make sense if this is a forum.